# Получить дочерние объекты из группировки

Tags: delphi, ole, corel-draw

Создали нам макет в Corel Draw. Чтобы не мучиться с редактированием каждого текстового поля (всё уже есть в БД), решено было автоматизировать процесс через OLE. Необходимо проанализировать и, если необходимо, заменить содержимое нескольких текстовых форм (Shape) - на скриншоте, к примеру, это "Тип_продукта_верх" и "Описание_верх":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Инициализация:

```
const
  filename = 'P:\CorelPassports\for_open_d.cdr';
var
  cdr:Variant;
  sh,sh1:Variant;
  shapes:array of Variant;
  s:string;
<...>

  try
    cdr:=createoleobject('CorelDRAW.Application');
  except
    // Обработка
  end;
  cdr.Visible:=true;
  try
     cdr.OpenDocument(filename);
  except
    // Обработка
  end;
```

С формой, не входящей в группу, всё просто:

```
  cdr.ActiveDocument.ClearSelection;
  sh:=cdr.ActivePage.FindShape('Тип_продукта_верх'); 
  // sh.Type = cdrTextShape =   6, т.е. текстовый тип
  // и мы можем дальше работать с текстом:
  s:=sh.Text.Story; 
<..>
```

А вот, если форма является группой, всё сложнее и непонятнее:

```
  sh:=cdr.ActivePage.FindShape('Описание_верх');
  // sh.Type = cdrGroupShape =  7, т.е. группа
  // и нужно получать доступ к членам группы
  // пробуем, как в VBA осуществить это через массив:

shapes:=sh.Shapes;
```

Вылетает ошибка "Invalid argument"

В чём подвох? Как получить все дочерние текстовые элементы группы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока формулировал вопрос и печатал его, появилась идея о том, что мой учебник по CQL (Corel Query Language) всё-таки староват и, возможно, какие-то структуры поменяли описание. Действительно, начиная (если ничего не путаю) с версии X3, метод Shapes возвращает не массив/коллекцию форм, а класс, предоставляющий доступ к коллекции. Поэтому, чтобы получить всю группу форм, достаточно такого кода:

```
var 
  i, cnt:integer

<..>

  sh1:=sh.Shapes; // не массив Variant, а просто Variant или OLEVariant, кому как нравится
  cnt:=sh1.Count; // число дочерних элементов
  for I := 1 to cnt do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(sh1.Item[i].Text.Story); // получаем доступ к свойствам дочерних форм через Item[i] 
  // Нумерация массива начинается с 1, а не с 0!!!
```